# Migration Issues from MarketingCloudSDK 7.6 to 8.0.1

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk

I am following this guide to migrate to the MarketingCloudSDK Version 8.0.1 https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html.

I removed the SDK from the Podfile. Then I added the **MobilePush** and **SFMCSDK** Frameworks via the SPM. Both frameworks I fixed to the latest releases. **SFMCSDK to 1.0.1** and **MobilePush to 8.0.1**. In order to get rid of the "Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model” error I manually copied the SDK Bundle to "**Copy Bundle Resources Section**".

[image: Copy Bundle Resources Section]

[image: SPM]

However, when I try to import the **MarketingCloudSDK** I get an compiler error **No such module 'MarketingCloudSDK'**.

[image: No such Module Error]

I am not sure if I added the Framework correctly as I am not exactly sure what this sentence in the migration guide means:

> Manually pull in the Resources/MarketingCloudSDK.bundle from the sources folder in the Mobile Push SPM and link it with the binary in build phase.

Any help to solve the "No such module" error would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Please check the Project Settings -> General -> My Target -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content to see if packages are listed in the import statement. I would also suggest cleaning the derived data and restarting the Xcode. The "No such module" error is not related to pulling in the MarketingCloudSDK.bundle.

Also, maybe checkout if You would be successful with our [Learning App](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/tree/spm/LearningApp)?

Once the "No such module" error is resolved, adding the MarketingCloudSDK.bundle is fairly easy. It could be as simple as drag & drop from its location (Resources/MarketingCloudSDK.bundle) to Your app directory, however I believe You have already done that part.